# Regex to replace all '&' which are in " " in a string....in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ajax, jquery

I have url in which the parameters contain '&' characters ..now i have to do an ajax call but the server sends exception on that..so the solution is to replace the '&' of parameters by %26 and then make the call...

e.g...

```
url = http://localhost.com/?q=java&industry="IT&web"&location="New-york & Florida"
```

The result must be...

```
= http://localhost.com/?q=java&industry="IT%26web"&location="New-york %26 Florida"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck with this string and want to try to encode it:

```
var url = "http://localhost.com/?q=java&industry=\"IT&web\"&location=\"New-york & Florida\"";
```

One option is to capture all quoted expressions (assuming they match, of course), and apply `encodeURIComponent` on them. The result is having the whole parameter encoded, including the quotes:

```
url = url.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, encodeURIComponent);
> http://localhost.com/?q=java&industry=%22IT%26web%22&location=%22New-york%20%26%20Florida%22
```

Similarly, you can replace only the ampersands if that's what you need:

```
url = url.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, function(g0){return g0.replace(/&/g, encodeURIComponent);});
> http://localhost.com/?q=java&industry="IT%26web"&location="New-york %26 Florida"
```

In both cases, this may clash with already-escaped characters, so again, the best solution is to fix the problem at its source, where the url is created.

Answer (score 8):

You must use:

```
query = encodeURIComponent (query);
```

Comment: that will replace all the & in the Url ..that i don't need to do ..i need only to replace the & which is in "" and after the '=' i.e which is the value of the parameter in my case parameters are industry and location...

Comment: before creating full url you must use encodeURIComponent for each $_GET variable

Comment: That will help but if the initial URl includes this pattern the what to do??

Comment: Initial URI must doesn't include those elements

Comment: In my case there is ..because it is actually the Url for faceting in search page....so the initial url will be there/....